# Scrolling a div notification fixed at top header and window

Tags: css, notifications, position, fixed

I would like to display a notification on a page with a header, like this:

Situation 1 : Scroll is top

> > The notification bar is fixed below header

Situation 2 : Scroll is middle or bottom

> > The notification bar is fixed to top of display.

A website example : https://loppist.com/products/coco-lapine/ketos
When you add to cart, a notification appears

Could someone help me ?